# new line from a text file

Tags: python

I have a file example.txt in this format:

```
a,b,c,d
```

and I want to convert it to:

```
a
b
c
d
```

I wrote this but it is not work:

```
with open('newline.txt', 'w') as f: 
    f.write (file("example.txt", "r").read().replace(",", "\n"))
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: The code you posted worked for me, as-is. Note, I'm using Python-2.7.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this as well:

```
with open('newline.txt', 'w') as f:  
    f.writelines (w + '\n' for w in open("example.txt").read().split(","))
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be:

```
with open('newline.txt', 'w') as f: 
    f.write (open("example.txt", "r").read().replace(",", "\n"))
```

It is stated in [documentary](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#file), that when opening a file, it’s preferable to use open() instead of invoking file() constructor directly

Comment: I tried it but the problem still the same. It doesn't go to new line

Comment: What are you getting in newline.txt?